# How to add Inkwell into the container text in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm very new to Flutter. It's awesome, no question, excellent environment. Currently i am trying to create a multi-paged app on flutter with some row and container. I have couple of container like that which is having a text.

```
        Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 50,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.2,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                color: ColorConstants.korangeColor,
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  "Food Poisoning Symptoms",
                  style: GoogleFonts.spartan(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    color: ColorConstants.kwhiteColor,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

I did wrap my container with Inkwell and try something like:

```
      Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 50,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.2,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              color: ColorConstants.korangeColor,
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                  "Food Poisoning Symptoms",
                  style: GoogleFonts.spartan(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    color: ColorConstants.kwhiteColor,
                  ),
                ),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => FoodPoisoning(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),

            ),
          ),
```

But i got black screen with that error log with black screen of page:

> Failed assertion: line 1920 pos 12: 'hasSize'

I specifically don't understand what is happening with my code. Can someone  tell me what's the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `Container` with `InkWell` instead.

```
Row(children: [
      InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => FoodPoisoning(),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: Container(
            height: 50,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.2,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              color: ColorConstants.korangeColor,
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                "Food Poisoning Symptoms",
                style: GoogleFonts.spartan(
                  fontSize: 15,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  color: ColorConstants.kwhiteColor,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ))
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using this method by creating a StatelessWidget separate from the one in Flutter

**The goal :** Is to prevent the shadow from appearing on the container size when clicking on the text , like this :

```
class InkWellApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function onTap;
  final Widget child;

  final BorderRadius borderRadius;

  const InkWellApp(
      {Key key, this.onTap, this.child, this.borderRadius = BorderRadius.zero})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        child,
        Positioned.fill(
            child: Material(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          borderRadius: borderRadius,
          child: InkWell(
            borderRadius: borderRadius,
            onTap: onTap,
          ),
        )),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

It is **applied** as follows:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(

        children: [
          .
          .
          .
          .

          InkWellApp(child: Text('Anything Text onTap .....'), onTap: (){
            /// onTap Function her ...
          },)
        ],

      ),

    );
  }
}
```

> Note: You can use GestureDetector instead but no shadow appears when
> you click

It may be that this solution is not useful to you at this time, but the solution to your problem is as follows:

```
Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [

            Container(
              height: 50,
              width: MediaQuery
                  .of(context)
                  .size
                  .width / 1.2,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                 color: ColorConstants.korangeColor,
              ),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => FoodPoisoning(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                child: Text(
                  "Food Poisoning Symptoms",
                  //Add this line instead of Center() widget
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: GoogleFonts.spartan(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    color: ColorConstants.kwhiteColor,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),

          ],
        )
```